# Why can I not assign an int or null to an int?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have the following class:

```
public class QuestionDetail
{
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionResponseToClient
{
    public int? ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I used the int? as I want to be able to return a null to the client if the user is not in the admin role.

In my code I check for this with:

```
bool adminUser = User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

I then create a new object as follows:

```
var questionResponseToClient = new QuestionResponseToClient
{
    QuestionId = (adminUser == true) ? questionDetails.QuestionId : null,
    ...
    ...
```

But this fails with the message:

> Error 1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no 
>   implicit conversion between 'int' and ''

Can someone give me some advice as to why this is happening?

Comment: Cast one of the options to `int?` manually. This has been asked many times before.

Comment: `questionDetails.QuestionId` is an int, `QuestionId` is a `Nullable<int>`. You will need to cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both side of conditional operator must return same type or there should exist an implicit conversion. 
There is no implicit conversion between `int` and `null`, so you have to cast either operand to `int?`

```
QuestionId = (adminUser == true) ? (int?) questionDetails.QuestionId : null,
```

---

Or you can do:

```
QuestionId = (adminUser == true) ? questionDetails.QuestionId : (int?) null,
```

Since there is an implicit conversion between `int` and `int?` (`Nullable<int>`).

Comment: An `int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`, which makes it more obvious that they're different types.

Answer (score 2):

For it to work you have to assign a nullable int.

```
QuestionId = (adminUser == true) ? questionDetails.QuestionId : new int?
```

That's what the error says it's impossible to determine the type, you are only sending null which is not a type so you need to tell what type you want.
The conditional expression needs either identical types on both branches, or needs to be an implicit conversion from one of the types to the other.

Comment: So will new int? be the same as a null ?

Comment: no it will be a nullable int

Comment: `new int?()`, `default(int?)` and `(int?)null` are all the same: an `int?` with `HasValue == false`, which is treated by the C# compiler like `null`. (look up more about how the `Nullable<T>` struct works if you want to understand this in more detail)

Answer (score 1):

The type of your conditional expression can't be determined by the compiler. Try this instead:

```
QuestionId = (adminUser == true) ? (int?)questionDetails.QuestionId : null
```